# Appending 100 random numbers to a file in Bash

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to make a Python program that is based on the 20w14infinte Minecraft snapshot. The 'world gen.' was going to be made in Python 3 using `os.system()` but the lines were very long so I made an SH script to make the worlds for me. It should append a random number between 0 and 32767, the 16-bit limit, to the end of a file.

Here's my code:

Python:

```
# imports
import random
import os

# variables
game_name = "testing-world"

# functions
def mk_world():
    os.system(f"./mk_world.sh {game_name}")

mk_world()
```

Bash (`mk_world.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

game_name=$1

cd ./games/$game_name/worlds/

seed=$RANDOM

mkdir $seed
cd $seed
touch world.dimension

echo $RANDOM
ls

for i in {1..100} ;do
    echo $RANDOM > world.dimension
done

cat world.dimension
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in {1..100} ;do
    echo $RANDOM > world.dimension
done
```

This part will execute "echo $RANDOM > world dimension" 100 times, and ">" redirection means that world.dimension will be overwritten, so you should ">>" to append to the file

Possibly you want to do just the following:
echo $RANDOM >> world.dimension

Answer (score 0):

A possible Python solution would be something like:

```python
import random

# Open world.dimension in append mode
with open("world.dimension", "a") as world_dimension:
    # 100 times
    for i in range(100):
        # Write a random integer between 0 and 32767 to the file and
        # append a trailing newline character to split the lines
        world_dimension.write("{}\n".format(random.randint(0, 32767)))
```